# How to use field name as the hash table key on initialise, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, initialization, hashtable

I would like to use field.name as the key for the hash table on initialisation but I get an error saying that ":" is missing on init line, here how I tried

```
var field1 = document.getElementById("PRES_BK_LANG");
var field2 = document.getElementById("PRES_BK_CORR_MED");
var fields = {field1.name:[field1,"P"],field2.name:[field2,"O"]};
```

can this be done?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the object literal notation is only usable if the property names are hardcoded. You will have to use the object as a map to store your data:

```
var fields = {};
fields[field1.name] = [field1,"P"];
fields[field2.name] = [field2,"O"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write this instead.

```
var fields = {};
fields[field1.name] = [field1,"P"];
fields[field2.name] = [field2,"O"];
```

The reason is this kind of object construct (what you have written) treats the "key" as string literal instead of resolving it to the real string.